# How do I give a where clause or condition to get a value in json response using rest asssured

Tags: json, response, rest-assured

I need to extract the value of id where name == 'abc'. How can I do that?

here is the example of response:

```
    {
  "Text": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "name": "ABC"
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "name": "XYZ"
    },
    {
      "id": "789",
      "name": "DEF"
    }
]
}
```

So I need to extract the value of id where name =='ABC' should return me id value as 123. 
I need to use jayway restassured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GPath `findAll` feature

```
when().
    get("/restapi").
then().
    body("text.findAll{ it.name == 'ABC' }.id", hasItem("123"));
```